# Gremlin : Check for vertex existence if yes than proceed for further travelsal

Tags: datastax, gremlin, graphdb

Is there a way to do the below use case in our single query.

1. Check for a vertex for its existence with some id.
2. If exists then do the further traversals.

Currently, we are doing the above using two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything special if your only choice is to proceed if the element exists. In other words, if you have:

```
g.V(1).out()
```

If a vertex with `id` of "1" is not present, it will simply not traverse `out()` as none exists. If you have a need for alternative processing in the event that the vertex does NOT exist then you will need to use some form of branching logic (typically `coalesce()` or `choose()`). Here's some examples of [element existence checks](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) which demonstrate "get or create" types of operations that might be applicable to what you're doing.